# Was bedeutet "Hauses" in diesem Kontext

Tags: vocabulary

> alle Führungskräfte des **Hauses** mit dem fortgeschrittensten Managementwissen vertraut zu machen, das es zur Zeit gab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the genitiv of "Haus" (meaning "house" or "company").

EDIT:

The german word "Haus" has another meaning that might be of interest for this question:

When talking about aristocrats from certain tribes or clans you say: "Die Kaiser aus dem **Hause** Habsburg-Lothringen". In English: "The emperors from the **house** of Habsburg-Lorraine".

Here the word "Haus" or "house" has the meaning of "tribe" or "clan". And I think that the meaning of "company" comes from this.

Comment: Another meaning: "hotel"

Comment: @Stephie: A hotel is just a special type of a house. A house is a building where people are meant to live or to do their jobs. A bridge is a building but not a house. A hotel and a companies headquarter are houses.

Answer (score -1):

"Hauses" is somewhat pretentious sounding corporatespeak denoting the company.